# Set images position in absolute layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image setup inside an absolute panel.I am trying to set it's position via code.But I do not see any applicable method/property to set its position.

Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/marker" android:src="@drawable/marker" android:layout_y="106dp" android:layout_x="290dp"></ImageView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Here is my code to set its position

```
marker = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.marker);
        marker.//Can't find a method or property
```

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use `AbsoluteLayout`. It's deprecated. Use `FrameLayout`.
- With a FrameLayout, you can create a `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` object for your view, and specify the margin on the left and top.
- If you want to animate your view, you can use a `TranslateAnimation`.

If you need to add multiple elements, encapsulate them into a layout and put those underneath your FrameLayout.

Comment: I have two images in this app.How could I make image 1 move to a certain position on top of image 2?

Comment: Also have some buttons in the main layout.

Comment: Framelayout only support one image?

Comment: If you need to add multiple elements, encapsulate them into a layout and put those underneath your FrameLayout.