# How do I drop an Android ImageView object in a particular area on the screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-layoutparams

I'm just coming back to Android after a number of years doing C# on Windows and wanted to port my universal app to Android.  It's a version of Solitaire based on cribbage.  Essentially, what I've done is defined a relative layout containing a number of pre-defined ImageView locations.  I initially populated everything using dummy values for the cards to ensure the layout looked good.  With that done, I moved to implementing the game logic.  When I drag a card from the deck "drawCard", if the user releases it over one of the empty (and valid) ImageView objects, the value of the drawCard should be assigned to the empty ImageView object it was released over, and the drawCard should return to its original position, but with a new value based on the next card in the deck.  My problem is in calculating the position of the draw card to determine if it's hovering over a valid ImageView target or not.  Here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/gamePage"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.cardgames.tony.solitairecribbage.GamePageActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_game_page"
android:background="#041a01">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:id="@+id/hand1Card1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <!--android:src="@drawable/aofc"/>-->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:id="@+id/hand1Card2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"/>
        <!--android:src="@drawable/c3ofs"/-->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:id="@+id/hand1Card3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/hand2Card4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:id="@+id/hand1Card4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hand1Card1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

(Similar declarations are made for 3 other hands.  Below is the card deck and the drawCard, the one the user is dragging):

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardDeck"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b1fv"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:id="@+id/drawCard"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cardDeck"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardDeck"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardDeck"/>
```

What I did in the old days was use absolute positions to calculate the valid 'drop zones' for the cards.  With the relative layout, I'm not sure how to do this.  Ideally, I'd calculate the dead center coordinates of the card I'm dragging and the top left and bottom right coordinates of valid 'drop zones'.  If the coordinates were in between these values, the card would be released and a new card drawn at the original location as well.

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing, but it is not giving me accurate values:

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {                        

                    //Getting X and Y coordinates for event position
                    float tempX = event.getX();
                    float tempY = event.getY();

                    //Attempt to get dead center point for card being dragged:
                    int height = finalTempCardPicture.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
                    int width = finalTempCardPicture.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
                    tempX += width/2;
                    tempY += height/2;
```

Try to calculate the valid drop zone:

```
   //fixCardPosition tries to place the card in a valid empty ImageView
                    if (!fixCardPosition(tempX, tempY))
                    {
                        //Return the draw card to the deck if the move is invalid
                        layoutParams.topMargin = drawOriginY;
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = drawOriginX;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    }
```

Here's the logic for trying to determine the location:

```
        public boolean isDraggedToFirstHand(int xCoord, int yCoord)
{
    int topLeftExtentX;
    int topLeftExtentY;
    int bottomRightExtentX;
    int bottomRightExtentY;
    ImageView tempImage;
    tempImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hand1Card1);
    topLeftExtentX = tempImage.getLeft();
    topLeftExtentY = tempImage.getTop();
    tempImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hand1Card4);
    bottomRightExtentX = tempImage.getRight();
    bottomRightExtentY = tempImage.getBottom();
    return (xCoord >= topLeftExtentX && yCoord >= topLeftExtentY && xCoord < bottomRightExtentX && yCoord < bottomRightExtentY);
```

Here's what the layout should look like:

[Solitaire Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bjTW.jpg)

Sorry for the lengthy post, but I wanted to try and ensure I had sufficient info in here for my question to make sense.

Comment: I don't know if it completely solves your problem, but refer to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478805/setting-image-view-absolute-position

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236386/set-images-position-in-absolute-layout

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063282/put-image-in-an-absolute-position-in-a-linear-layout

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely helpful, but the real problem I'm having is trying to calculate the absolute position of the Drop Zone.  In the screen shot, you can see a 4x4 arrangement of cards.  Each column is one hand.  What I want to determine are the absolute coordinates of each hand, which would give me their respective Drop Zones.  If I have this info and can determine the absolute coordinates of the card being dragged, I can then do the necessary calculations to determine if a drop is valid or not.

Comment: When looking at the suggestions above, I found this post, which solved my problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17554835/6828469

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why ImageView's getX, getY, setX and setY do not represent the actual value in the Relative Layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411221/why-imageviews-getx-gety-setx-and-sety-do-not-represent-the-actual-value-in-t)